# Babel React transpiling to `fileName.Component` instead of just `Component`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I am having to call my react component as `component.Component`, like below. Also to note, the first part is the file name. If the rename the file, I have to say `(newFileName.LikeButton)`.
[image]

instead of

```
ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(LikeButton) , domContainer);
```

Any idea how I can resolve this? Here is my setup. My babel.config.json

```
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-react", "@babel/preset-env" ],
    "plugins": [ "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-umd" ]
}
```

my react component in `likeButton.jsx`

```
export class LikeButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { liked: false };
  }
 
  render() {
    if (this.state.liked) {
      return 'You liked this.';
    }

    return (<button onClick={() => this.setState({ liked: true }) }>
        Like
      </button>
      );
  }
}
```

Comment: Does the code run as expected, but you just want to make it shorter? Or are you saying that the transpiled code is referring to variables that don't exist and thus causing errors? Also, we'll probably need to see your import statements.

Comment: code runs fine.

Answer (score 0):

Warning, this answer is speculative (but too long for a comment)

I suspect your imports look something like this:

`import likeButton from './somePath/likeButton'`

but, because you are using named exports, (as opposed to default exports), your import should actually look like:

`import { LikeButton } from './somePath/likeButton'`

to "destructure" `LikeButton` from the module.

Comment: I agree this looks likely to be the issue, but if that is then the better option for the OP is to replace `export class ...` with `export default class ...`. In taht case all imports can remain as they are. (But we don't know if the OP is exporting anything else from these files - there are too many open questions imo to put a definitive answer here.)

Comment: @RobinZigmond I went the other way because of my inclination to avoid default exports. Maybe it's because of my focus on TypeScript, but I find default exports clunky and resistant to refactoring tooling. It seems [I'm not alone](https://www.google.com/search?q=avoid+default+exports)

Comment: I am not importing `LikeButton` anywhere. I get the transpiled `likeButton.js` file which I use as `script src` in HTML page. Updated in question above. I tried `export  default LikeButton` but that errors in react-dom ` Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.`

Comment: I just realised that the first part is the filename. So if I rename the file I have to call the component as `newFileName.LikeButton`

Comment: I think this is probably related to using UMD exports then. Why so?

Comment: tbh, I can't get any other module transpile to run on browser. I have the umd react.js so I assumed they should work well together. I don't have a single entry point to these components. like index.js or index.html. I want to build a collection of these independent components that I can use in my html as and when needed.

Comment: i came across this https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-modules-umd#default-semantics, so since then i have tried `"exactGlobals": true` in my babel.config. I have tried adding and removing `"type": "module"` from package.json. Still no joy.